# How to use the pixel array from an image in sfml

Tags: c++, arrays, pixel, sfml

I am new to sfml and want to process each pixel of an image separately.

The best way I see is to iterate over the the array of all pixels in this image. Sfml gives the handy function [sf::Image::getPixelsPtr()](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#ac6137a608a9efaae2735c13ff259c214) for this. Unfortunately I can't make sense of the returned array.

I don't understand the documentation for this, how exactly can I access the color values of a certain pixel in this array?

Comment: Do you want to do normal image processing? If you want to process all pixels in some specific way, you might want to render your texture to a `sf::RenderTexture` using a pixel shader that applies your transform to a `sf::Sprite`.

Answer (score 1):

**const Uint8* sf::Image::getPixelsPtr (       )   const**

*The returned value points to an array of RGBA pixels made of 8 bits integers components. The size of the array is width * height * 4 (getSize().x * getSize().y * 4). Warning: the returned pointer may become invalid if you modify the image, so you should never store it for too long. If the image is empty, a null pointer is returned.*

From what I understand, the image is in 8-bit RGBA, and they're giving you a Uint8 pointer at the beginning of the image, which would be the 'R' of the first pixel.

```cpp
// code edited. was saying 'sd' i changed to 'sf'
const UInt8* pByteBuffer = sf::Image::getPixelsPtr();

size_t numPixels = getSize().x + getSize().y;
for (int i = 0 ; i < numPixels; ++i)
    {
    UInt8 red   = pByteBuffer[4 * i];
    UInt8 green = pByteBuffer[4 * i + 1];
    UInt8 blue  = pByteBuffer[4 * i + 2];
    UInt8 alpha = pByteBuffer[4 * i + 3];
    }
```

If you want to iterate on PIXELS as a whole rather than on single colors within pixels, you can reinterpret_cast the pointer they're giving you:

```cpp
const UInt8* pByteBuffer = sf::Image::getPixelsPtr();
const UInt32* pPixelBuffer = reinterpret_cast<const UInt32*>(pByteBuffer);

size_t numPixels = getSize().x * getSize().y;
for (int i = 0; i < numPixels; ++i)
    {
    uint32_t pixel = pPixelBuffer[i];
    }
```

Comment: Correct, except that you're using the wrong index for your image pixels in the `for()` loop and when accessing an array you're dereferencing it, so you'd get `Uint8` rather than `UInt8*`.

Comment: @Mario My bad. I use to work with images stored inside a vector<Byte>.

Comment: @O'Neil corrected. Though I can't help myself but think their method should have been named getPixelsCPtr.